# Not able to get the HTML report while running Jmeter Test Script from non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a non GUI Jmeter script. It gives the test result in the bin folder however when I am opening the index.html it shows me the result as below screenshot.

Running the script for 2 mins with 10 users.

Below is the Result:

```
summary +     31 in 00:00:07 =    4.2/s Avg:  1434 Min:   629 Max:  2997 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 10 Started: 10 Finished: 0
summary +    184 in 00:00:29 =    6.3/s Avg:  1357 Min:    93 Max:  4816 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 10 Started: 10 Finished: 0
summary =    215 in 00:00:37 =    5.8/s Avg:  1368 Min:    93 Max:  4816 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    159 in 00:00:30 =    5.3/s Avg:  1120 Min:    94 Max:  3953 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 10 Started: 10 Finished: 0
summary =    374 in 00:01:07 =    5.6/s Avg:  1263 Min:    93 Max:  4816 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    183 in 00:00:30 =    6.1/s Avg:  1154 Min:    91 Max:  4001 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 10 Started: 10 Finished: 0
summary =    557 in 00:01:37 =    5.7/s Avg:  1227 Min:    91 Max:  4816 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    157 in 00:00:25 =    6.3/s Avg:   966 Min:    92 Max:  2953 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 10 Finished: 10
summary =    714 in 00:02:02 =    5.9/s Avg:  1169 Min:    91 Max:  4816 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCvNI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to open `index.html` file which is not sufficient, there should be `content` and `sbadmin-2-1.0.7` folders as well:

[image]

If the folders are not there - it might be the case your JMeter installation is broken somehow. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries and the integrity of the [`report-template` folder](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.5/bin/report-template), maybe a good idea would be [re-installing the latest version of JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation#install)

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have those folders in the path where I am trying to get the output.

Comment: Re-installing did the trick. Thanks a ton. U made my day :-)

Comment: @SubhaneilSengupta if your question was answered, please [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147532/344280).